# Need Java Equivalent of this C# Encryption code

Tags: java, c#, encryption

I have the following c# code but need the exact same algorithm in Java.  Whether the c# code is quality, I can do nothing about.  I only care if the Java encoded string is equivalent.

```
    //Run GetToken to get encrypted string
    var token = GetToken(AMessage, account_name, api_key);

    private static byte[] GetBytes(string value, byte[] salt, int length)
    {
        var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(value, salt);
        return deriveBytes.GetBytes(length);
    }

    private static string GetToken(string session, string accountName, string apiKey)
    {
        byte[] encrypted;

        using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            var salt = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(apiKey);
            var key = GetBytes(accountName, salt, aes.KeySize / 8);
            var vector = GetBytes(accountName, salt, aes.BlockSize / 8);

            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV = vector;

            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
            {
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
                    {
                        writer.Write(session);
                    }
                }
            }
            encrypted = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
    }
```

Comment: `does not seem to work` is not a good description of the problem. Please be as detailed as possible.

Comment: I edited the question to say instead: "does not encrypt the same as the c# code"

Comment: I could remove the second half of the question where I added additional details and supplied my java code "attempt" and my questions would be the same.  I just need equivalent code.  The c# code works.  But I don't know how to do it in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to cobble together the answer with the help of a friend.  I thought it would be helpful to post the answer so people looking found more than unanswered questions.  I know there are lots of encryption questions out there and the c# encryption method above is probably not recommended.  Hopefully this c# to java conversion helps someone.  Below is the java code answer for the above c# code question.

Enjoy.

```
private static String Encrypt(String DecryptedText, String accountName, String apiKey) {
    byte[] EncryptedStr = {};

    if (accountName.length() < 5 || apiKey.length() < 5) {
        System.out.println("Name too short");
        return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(EncryptedStr);
    }
    try {
        byte[] salt = apiKey.getBytes();
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");

        KeySpec KeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(accountName.toCharArray(), salt, 1000, 256);
        SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(KeySpec);

        KeySpec VectorSpec = new PBEKeySpec(accountName.toCharArray(), salt, 1000, 128);
        SecretKey vector = (SecretKey) factory.generateSecret(VectorSpec);

        SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "AES");

        byte[] ivKeyBytes = vector.getEncoded();
        byte[] iv = new byte[16]; // Get IV bytes from the
        for (int i = 0; i < iv.length; ++i)
                iv[i] = ivKeyBytes[i];
        IvParameterSpec ivParm = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        Log("Salt:", false);
        Log(salt, true);
        Log("Key:", false);
        Log(secretKey.getEncoded(), true);
        Log("Vector:", false);
        Log(iv, true);

        // IN C# they are using KeySize=256, Mode=CBC, Padding=PKCS7,
        // PKCS7 padding doesn't exist in java so use PKCS5 and hope it works correctly.
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        // NOTE: Added ivParam to initialize the IV parameter, w/o the first block is off.
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivParm);
        EncryptedStr = cipher.doFinal(DecryptedText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exc:" + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

    return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(EncryptedStr);
}
```

}